# Simple division + remainder method error

Tags: java, arrays

When programming a simple method resource to calculate division and remainder of integers input through a 2 dimensional array, eclipse marked the error that the method type was not applicable for the arguments.

I am creating a utility .class to import into other .class files so I can call the methods instead of coding long lines of simple math operations over and over. The parameters for all of the methods are input in arrays.

Here is a copy of the code for the method and the called method in question.

```
    static int iadd(int[] x) {
    int y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y += x[i];
    }
    return y;
}

    static int divrem(int[][] x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < x[0].length; i++) {
        int a = iadd(x[0][i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < x[1].length; i++) {
        int b = iadd(x[1][i]);
    }
```

I also have code for adding doubles, but I don't think I can take the nearest whole dividend of a double.

```
    static double dadd(double[] x) {
    double y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y += x[i];
    }
    return y;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb. Can someone please explain to me how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I needed to set the input parameter to iadd() to an array instead of a single integer.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to acheive in your `divrem` method - the variables `a` and `b` and local to the `for` loops **and** also will be overwritten for each iteration of the loop - do you want `+=` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iadd(int[] x)` accepts an int array but you are calling it with a single int.

```
iadd(x[0][i]);
```

Removing one of the `[]` deferences will pass a single dimensional int array...

```
iadd(x[i]);
```

I'm not sure what your math is trying to achieve this might not produce the correct result, but this is the cause of the compile time error.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem. I'm a newbie at java so I'm trying to apply concepts I've recently learned, those concepts being calling and declaring methods, arrays, and returning values.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to pass a 1D array to `iadd()` but if your only running that on `array[0]` and `array[1]` you can do away with the loops in `divrem()`.